# Swift: 'request for rect at invalid index path

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path 
(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4})'
```

What can be the issue. Im using table.estimatedRowHeight and automatically adjust row height functions for dynamic height of cells to adjust with my label. Any issue here?

Comment: Add your code where you are getting this crash

Comment: use exceptional breakpoint so you ll get know where your app is crashing.

Comment: if you don't know how to add exceptional break point check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode.